# Do continuous functions always preserve convergence in probability?

Tags: probability, general-topology, probability-theory, convergence-divergence, continuity

> Suppose $(S_0, T_0)$ and $(S_1, T_1)$ are two topological spaces and $f:S_0 \to S_1$ is a continuous function. Now, suppose, that $X, X_1, X_2, ...$ is a sequence of random elements of $S_0$, that satisfies the condition that $\{X_n\}_{n \in \mathbb{N}}$ converges in probability to $X$. Is it always true, that $\{f(X_n)\}_{n \in \mathbb{N}}$ converges in probability to $f(X)$?

The definition of convergence in probability here is the following one:

> We say that a sequence $\{X_n\}_{n \in \mathbb{N}}$ of random elements of a topological space $(S, T)$ *converges in probability* to $X$ iff $\forall U \in T$ such that $P(X \in U) \neq 0$ we have $\lim_{n \to \infty} P(X_n \in U| X \in U) = 1$

However, I have no idea how to apply this definition in order to get the desired result.

Comment: $Y_n \to Y$ in probability iff every subsequence of $(Y_n)$ has  a further subsequence converging almost surely to $Y$. This implies your result.

Comment: with probability **1**

Comment: But where we use function f? I dont understand, please write IT step by step :(

Comment: Is this a question about convergence in probability or about convergence with probability 1?  They are different things, and your original statement did not make it clear which one you meant.

Comment: Im sorry, i think about convergence in Probability

Answer (score 1):

Suppose $U$ is an open set in $(S_1, T_1)$ and $V := \{a \in S_0|f(a) \in U\}$ is a preimage of $U$ under $f$. Then $f(X) \in U$ iff $X$ is in $V$. The same holds for $X_n$. Thus $P(f(X_n) \in U| f(X) \in U) = P(X_n \in V| X \in V)$. And $V$ is open, because $f$ is continuous. Thus $\lim_{n \to \infty} P(f(X_n) \in U| f(X) \in U) = \lim_{n \to \infty} P(X_n \in V| X \in V) = 1$ Q.E.D.